# stanford NLP training sentiment model

Tags: stanford-nlp

I'm working on the kaggle competition for Rotten Tomatoes NLP prediction.

The training set format was parsed as such:

> PhraseId   SentenceId  Phrase  Sentiment
>
> 1  1   A series of escapades demonstrating the adage that what is good for the goose is also good for the gander , some of which occasionally amuses but none of which amounts to much of a story .    1
>
> 2  1   A series of escapades demonstrating the adage that what is good for the goose   2

However, the training set formula must look like:

> (3 (2 (2 The) (2 Rock)) (4 (3 (2 is) (4 (2 destined) (2 (2 (2 (2 (2 to) (2 (2 be) (2 (2 the) (2 (2 21st) (2 (2 (2 Century) (2 's)) (2 (3 new) (2 (2 ``) (2 Conan)))))))) (2 '')) (2 and)) (3 (2 that) (3 (2 he) (3 (2 's) (3 (2 going) (3 (2 to) (4 (3 (2 make) (3 (3 (2 a) (3 splash)) (2 (2 even) (3 greater)))) (2 (2 than) (2 (2 (2 (2 (1 (2 Arnold) (2 Schwarzenegger)) (2 ,)) (2 (2 Jean-Claud) (2 (2 Van) (2 Damme)))) (2 or)) (2 (2 Steven) (2 Segal))))))))))))) (2 .)))

Here's a snippet of the python code that I'm using:

> ```
>   phrasefind=str(train['Phrase'][i])+" " or " "+str(train['Phrase'][i]) or str(train['Phrase'][i])
>     phrase=train['Phrase'][i]
>     sent=rreplace(sent,phrasefind,"("+str(train['Sentiment'][i])+" "+str(phrase)+") ",1)
> ```

with the result:

> (1 (2 (2 (2 A) series) of (2 escapades) (2 (2 demonstrating) the adage) (2 that) (2 what) is good for the goose) (2 is) (2 also) (3 good) (2 for) (2 the) (2 gander) (2 ,) (2 (2 some) of which) (2 occasionally) (3 amuses) (2 but) (2 none) (2 of which) (2 amounts) (2 to) (2 much) (2 of) (2 a story) .)

However, the sentiment package from Stanford won't recognize this format (works fine for their train.txt)
It is throwing the error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: null

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I am currently learning how to train the model myself.

Looking at your train.txt the issue is down to you not scoring some of the words. I have just made these changes to your result and the command line is successfully adding it to my model:

```
(1 (2 (2 (2 A) series) (2 of) (2 escapades) (2 (2 demonstrating) (2 the) (2     adage)) (2 that) (2 what) (2 is) (3 good) (2 for) (2 the) (2 goose) (2 is) (2 also) (3 good) (2 for) (2 the) (2 gander) (2 ,) (2 (2 some) (2 of) (2 which)) (2 occasionally) (3 amuses) (2 but) (2 none) (2 of which) (2 amounts) (2 to) (2 much) (2 of) (2 a story) (2 .))
```